# Make it 100% of all

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 3 dropdown boxes, in which there are values of 10 to 100. I want user to select cumulative value of 100 from all dropdown boxes. 
Which means, if I select 20 from the first dropdown box the next 2 dropdown should be left with the options of selecting total of 100

What I have done so far is here: [CHECK IT HERE (JS FIDDLE)](http://jsfiddle.net/rzBej/26/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="foreign" class="me">
    <option value="">Foreign Policy</option>
    <option value="10">10%</option>
    <option value="20">20%</option>
    <option value="30">30%</option>
    <option value="40">40%</option>
    <option value="50">50%</option>
    <option value="60">60%</option>
    <option value="70">70%</option>
    <option value="80">80%</option>
    <option value="90">90%</option>
    <option value="100">100%</option>
</select>
<select id="economy" class="me">
    <option value="">Economy Policy</option>
    <option value="10">10%</option>
    <option value="20">20%</option>
    <option value="30">30%</option>
    <option value="40">40%</option>
    <option value="50">50%</option>
    <option value="60">60%</option>
    <option value="70">70%</option>
    <option value="80">80%</option>
    <option value="90">90%</option>
    <option value="100">100%</option>
</select>
<select id="social" class="me">
    <option value="">Social Policy</option>
    <option value="10">10%</option>
    <option value="20">20%</option>
    <option value="30">30%</option>
    <option value="40">40%</option>
    <option value="50">50%</option>
    <option value="60">60%</option>
    <option value="70">70%</option>
    <option value="80">80%</option>
    <option value="90">90%</option>
    <option value="100">100%</option>
</select>
<br />

<span id="message"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
/*var total = new Array();
$('#foreign option').each(function() {
    total.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(total);*/

var total = 100;
var ids = ['foreign', 'social', 'economy'];
var current_selected;

$('.me').change(function() {
    current_selected = $(this).attr('id');
    var socval = $('#' + current_selected + ' option:selected').val();
    total = total - socval;

    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), ids) > -1) {
        ids.splice($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), ids), 1);

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {

        $('#' + ids[i] + ' option').each(function() {

            if ($(this).val() >= total) {

                    $(this).attr('disabled', true);

            } else {
                $(this).attr('disabled', false);
            }

        });

    }


    if (total <= 0) {
        total = 100;
    }
    console.log(total);

    ids.push(current_selected);

});
```

It is pretty much working, with some minor faults.

**UPDATE**
I think I solved it.

[SOLVED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rzBej/61/)

Thanks who helped.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Changing:

`if ($(this).val() >= total) {`

to

`if ($(this).val() > total) {`

solves the problem of only being able to select upto 90%

[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rzBej/27/)

**Update**

With regard to changing values, i'd probably take a forward-looking approach and reset the value of the forward selects. Something like:

```
var selectIds = ['first', 'second', 'third']

$('select').change(function(){
var currentIndex = $.inArray($(this).attr('id'), selectIds);

for(var i = currentIndex + 1; i < selectIds.length; i++)
{
    $('#' + selectIds[i]).val("0");
}

});
```

This basically resets the value of select items in the chain that are further ahead than the current select box being used.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SQefz/)

You'll also want to look ahead when doing the disables. You should only be disabling items in the select lists further down the chain from the current select. The first select list should always be able to choose any value and the following selects filtered based on that. This fits in well with the above approach.

Comment: I know that and I have done that too. What i want now is to get the all the dropdowns revive means I changed my mind and now I want to select 80 from the first and 10 from 2 others. I hope you get my point.

Answer (score 0):

I did another version of your code, plus fixing the bug

http://jsfiddle.net/rzBej/62/

```
$('.me').change(function() {
    var totalSoFar = 0;
    $('.me').each(function() {
        totalSoFar += +$(this).val();
    });

    var tmp = 100 - totalSoFar;
    $('.me').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('option').each(function() {
            $this.prop('disabled', $this.attr('value') > tmp);
        });
    })
});​
```

Comment: -, not xhtml valid! you should rather use `$(this).removeProp('disabled');` and for performance: **reuse `$(this)` by storing it in a scoped variable!!**

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair From the docs http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/ - Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

Comment: seriously, read the docs before you comment and telling someone is wrong

Comment: @NiftyDude I am only left to select till 90%. No problem for your wrong answer

Comment: @MurtazaHussain hm, you can only select up to 90%? No I was telling Andreas about that, not you